# IIS + SharePoint 2013 + CMIS: Disable Multi-part SOAP Response

Tags: iis, sharepoint, soap, multipart, cmis

I have activated CMIS in a SharePoint 2013 hosted in IIS 8.5, the problem is that I'm able to invoke the SOAP services but the response is always returned with Content-Type: multi-part / related which is not supported by the source application (and it won't).

Could anybody please help me to disable the multi-part content-type? I have search about it for days and I have been exploring all the SharePoint and IIS options without any luck.

The problem is also that I'm not sure who is sending it as multi-part: CMIS, SharePoint, IIS... although I think is IIS as I at least could change the response header adding a custom header from IIS, but I don't find any way to disable the multi-part thing...

This is an example, ignore the response content...

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 998
**Content-Type: multipart/related;** type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:4748e8de-7139-47e4-914e-1d42beac1762+id=2";start-info="text/xml"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: ec016e9d-8e7d-7035-4d00-69b3136bea29
request-id: ec016e9d-8e7d-7035-4d00-69b3136bea29
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 41
SPIisLatency: 4
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:31:38 GMT


**--uuid:4748e8de-7139-47e4-914e-1d42beac1762+id=2**
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
.......
....
....
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that the Service is deployed as WCF Service (.svc), so the new question is:

How can I change the messageEncoding to "Text" for all the Operations in an Service that I have no access to the code and is deployed as .svc?

ServiceName = ObjectService
Binding = ObjectServicePortBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally using the REST API instead of SOAP, so the problem has disappeared, although I'll never know the answer to the original question :(

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if you can turn it off. The CMIS specification mandates the use of MTOM (multipart). And it's actually necessary to transfer document content.

Comment: But I suppose that there is someway to convert the xml before sending it out from IIS, any clue?